# Reading Sudokus from text file and applying backtracking

Tags: python, json, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I have just begun with python, so excuse me if these are noob questions or if the questions are already answered.
I am trying to read multiple sudoku puzzles and apply the algorithm I found online. The code utilizes a grid(`list[list[int]]`) setup. I have tried looking for a solution online, but all I found was that I should convert the .txt file to a JSON file and continue from there.

**The `.txt` file looks like this**:

```
AME: sudoku
TYPE: SUD
COMMENT: 5 sudokus

SUDOKU 1
034000600
002600080
068300007
003001005
059060072
000520046
205906000
000408050
000007004

SUDOKU 2
000504000
000089020
785000000
002346008
040290050
860000000
030007042
400060805
608005030

SUDOKU 3
040000300
036072000
078060400
083000600
000300005
025008070
300004800
000000024
764089530

SUDOKU 4
000074900
000000046
079000300
600728009
980503000
037940050
200000000
008030060
060490023

SUDOKU 5
026030470
000200510
700900020
509000000
000050000
000000307
080009001
034006000
095070640

EOF
```

---

**Code from online**:

```
def is_valid(grid, r, c, k):
    not_in_row = k not in grid[r]
    not_in_column = k not in [grid[i][c] for i in range(9)]
    not_in_box = k not in [grid[i][j] for i in range(r//3*3, r//3*3+3) for j in range(c//3*3, c//3*3+3)]
    return not_in_row and not_in_column and not_in_box


def solve(grid, r=0, c=0):
    if r == 9:
        return True
    elif c == 9:
        return solve(grid, r+1, 0)
    elif grid[r][c] != 0:
        return solve(grid, r, c+1)
    else:
        for k in range(1, 10):
            if is_valid(grid, r, c, k):
                grid[r][c] = k
                if solve(grid, r, c+1):
                    return True
                grid[r][c] = 0
        return False
        
grid = [
    [0, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [9, 0, 0, 7, 3, 4, 6, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 4, 9],
    [0, 3, 5, 0, 9, 0, 4, 8, 0],
    [0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
    [0, 7, 6, 0, 1, 0, 9, 2, 0],
    [3, 1, 0, 9, 7, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 9, 1, 8, 2, 0, 0, 3],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 0]
]
solve(grid)
print(*grid, sep='\n')
```

Instead of the static grid that needs to be inputted, I would instead use the `.txt` file. I just couldn't find anything to help me solve the issue at hand. This might be because I am new to python or I need help understanding how to convert to JSON files.

[How to convert txt file into json using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748879/how-to-convert-txt-file-into-json-using-python) I have looked at this, but I am unsure if this is even the right approach.

Any feedback is appreciated, or even a nod in the right direction is also helpful.

Comment: "all I found was that I should convert the .txt file to a JSON file and continue from there"—that's not a very helpful suggestion.

Comment: So... the Sudoku code is something you found online? And your question is how to parse the input file? Forget about JSON. Do you know how to open files and iterate over the lines they contain?

Comment: There's no need to convert to JSON at all. However, you will need to 1.) open the file, 2.) skip (or read) the header, and then 3.) read each sudo into a list of lists of integers, making sure you split and convert the strings of numbers correctly

Comment: @Grismar Thanks for the feedback I will look into it more and try it out

Comment: @Chris I think I am missing the part of iterating so I will look into it more ty for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could read the sudoku text file into a dictionary of `list[list[int]]`, i.e. `dict[str, list[list[int]]]`:

```
def read_sudokus(fn: str) -> dict[str, list[list[int]]]:
    sudokus = {}
    with open(fn) as f:
        [next(f) for _ in range(4)]  # skip the header
        while True:
            name = next(f).strip()
            if name == 'EOF':
                break
            sudokus[name] = [list(map(int, next(f).strip())) for _ in range(9)]
            next(f)  # skip blank line
    return sudokus


ss = read_sudokus('sudoku.txt')
print(ss)
```

Output:

```
{'SUDOKU 1': [[0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0], [0, 6, 8, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7], [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5], [0, 5, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0, 7, 2], [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 4, 6], [2, 0, 5, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 8, 0, 5, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 4]], 'SUDOKU 2':  etc.
```

This assumes a standard sudoku size of 9x9 of course.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be to read the lines of the txt file out and then search for the sudokus.
It would look something like this:

```
with open('sudoku.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

puzzles = []

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    sudoku = []
    if line.startswith('SUDOKU'):
        # next 9 lines will be our puzzle
        for j in range(1, 10):
            sudoku.append([*lines[i+j].strip()]) # strip gets rid of the newline character, the * splits the string into a list of characters
        puzzles.append(sudoku)
```

The puzzles list now contains a list of lists, but all of the characters are strings right now, I will leave the conversion into integers to you.